# AlarmManager working for only a short span of time set

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager

I have used an AlarmManager as:

```
 final Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);
 alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp1.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp1.getCurrentMinute());


            myIntent.putExtra("extra", "yes");
           myIntent.putExtra("quote id", String.valueOf(quote));
            pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Addevent.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent); 
}
});
```

This works fine if the time is set near to few hrs but if the span is greater like 9hrs , it the `onReceive()` method of the AlarmReceiver is immediately called, when the alarm is created.Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: That code is horked up.  The definition of `calendar` is in the wrong place...

Comment: I'm using it in Button onClick , have updated the code . Now?

Comment: uhhh.. no.  The definition of `calendar` is still at the end of the last line in the code sample.  I'm pretty sure it belongs up near the definition of `myIntent`

Comment: Oh i'm sorry ! that was a code copying mistake. I've defined it there only (check the edited code)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the kind of time that corresponds to the flags you use in the call to `set`.  The two `ELAPSED_REALTIME_...` flags correspond to time since boot (`elapsedRealTime`).  The two `RTC_...` flags correspond to time since the epoch (`currentTimeMillis`).

If you are scheduling a repeating even, be aware that the `AlarmManager` will not schedule tasks in the past.  Since scheduling requires communication with a different process, it may, occasionally, take more than a millisecond to schedule.  If you schedule the first occurrence less than a few ms in the future, it may just disappear.

**Edited to add:**

Finally, not clear how your code is supposed to work (what is in `tp1`) but you are using the `Calendar` method `set`, not `add`.  `set` simply sets the value of the named field.  It does not "carry" to the next field.

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet for my requirement ? Also, i need to set up more than 1 alarm  and tp1 is the TimePicker.

Comment: Sure!  I charge $220/hr.

Comment: Awesome!  Please pick a correct answer or add your own.  Share the insight!

Comment: `pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Addevent.this, 0, myIntent, 0);`  solved that !

Answer (score 0):

Please find code snippet which I have used to schedule Alarm manager to trigger the event on next day.

```
 public void scheduleAlarm(..) {

            // time at which alarm will be scheduled here alarm is scheduled at 1 day from current time, 
            // we fetch  the current time in milliseconds and added 1 day time
            // i.e. 24*60*60*1000= 86,400,000   milliseconds in a day       
            Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+24*60*60*1000;

            // create an Intent and set the class which will execute when Alarm triggers, here we have
            // given AlarmReciever in the Intent, the onRecieve() method of this class will execute when
            // alarm triggers.
            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);

            // create the object
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            //set the alarm for particular time
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

            Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled for Tommrrow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: But I guess this won't work if i need to set an Alarm say, after an hour or will it still ?